# Three ways to sum the values of letters in words

Tags: python, comparative-review

I've created these 3 functions to count the value of letters in a word.

All these functions are functionally the same.

Apparently List comprehensions (`count_word3`) are usually seen as the most pythonic in these situations. But to me it is the least clear of the 3 examples.

Have I stumbled across something that is so simple that lambdas are acceptable here or is "the right thing to do" to use the list comprehension?

Or is there something better?

```
def count_word1(w):
    def count(i, a):
        return i + ord(a) - 64
    return reduce(count, w, 0)

def count_word2(w):
    return reduce(lambda a,b : a + ord(b) - 64, w, 0)

def count_word3(w):
    vals = [ord(c) - 64 for c in w]
    return sum(vals)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how's example 3 the least readable? I would write it a little better but you've got it right already:

```
def count_word3(word): 
    return sum(ord(c) - 64 for c in word)
```

Comment: I've probably just done too much scala :-). 
I'm just asking for opinions from the python community to refine my python style.

Answer (score 1):

These are the most readable for me:

```
sum((ord(letter) - ord('A') + 1) for letter in word)
```

Or

```
def letter_value(letter):
    return ord(letter) - ord('A') + 1

sum(map(letter_value, word))
```

btw, the code might break for non-ASCII strings.